# Why are ammonium chloride and ammonium hydroxide used in calcium salt detection?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, acid-base, experimental-chemistry

On adding $\ce{ (NH4)2CO3 }$ solution to $\ce{ Ca^{2+} }$ aqueous salt solution, $\ce{ CaCO3 }$ is formed as a white precipitate, which confirms the presence of the cation.

While doing the test in my school laboratory, we were given a list of procedures to follow; for $\ce{ Ca^{2+} }$ it read:

> Experiment: To the original solution added a small amount of $\ce{ NH4Cl }$, and an excess of $\ce{ NH4OH }$, followed by solid $\ce{ (NH4)2CO3 }$
>
> Observation: white ppt

Why do we need to add $\ce{ NH4Cl }$ and $\ce{ NH4OH }$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to fix the carbon in solution so it doesn't volatize as $\ce{CO2}$, since the equilibrium $$\ce{H2CO3 <=> CO2 + H2O}$$ favours the product side. By adding a base ($\ce{NH4OH}$), you shift the water ionization equilibrium, which in turn shifts the carbonic acid dissociation equilibrium. $\ce{NH4Cl}$ serves to regulate the $pH$ as a buffer. With your carbonate in solution, it is then able to precipitate as a solid by adding calcium.

Using a strong base would hinder the solid precipation by favouring the solubilization of ions, justifying the use of ammonium hydroxide.

Comment: I am unable to understand the equilibrium you've mentioned. I have two doubts: (1) Adding $\ce{(NH4)2CO3}$ to the solution produces $\ce{CO3^{2-}}$ ions and not $\ce{H2CO3}$, so why have you taken the latter in the LHS of your equilibrium? (2) Re: "favours the product side" In any aqueous solution, water is in excess. So, shouldn't the equilibrium favor the _reactant_ side instead? Thanks for your answer!

Comment: When we're dealing with equilibrium chemistry, having a certain species in solution means having *all* species that the particular species will allow from association or dissociation with other ions. The amount of each species is then dictated by the set of equilibrium constants.  Regarding the excess of water, it is true that water always wins the concentration fight in solution as a solvent, but it wins so hard it doesn't even enter the discussion: water is ommited from the equilibrium constant expression because its concentration remains essentially constant.

Comment: Carbon dioxide still prevails with respect to carbonic acid: put a $\ce{CO2}$ atmosphere over liquid water and much of it will dissolve and convert to the acid form, but most of it will stay as $\ce{CO2}$.